# What factors, beside blood-type, are considered a "good match" for organ transplants?

Tags: organ-donation, transplant-rejection

Matchmaker, matchmaker, make me a match; find me a find; catch me a catch!

I know there are probably a whole litany of **factors that are considered to match organ donors with those needing organs so that the transplant is not rejected. What are these factors?**

Blood type is obvious (as well as medical history to alcohol and substance abuse, etc). What else? Age plays a role depending on what is being donating, but not on everything, right? **Does gender matter? What else?**

Are organs transported on dry ice to keep them as viable as long as possible? **What is the means by which they are transported? How long from death or extraction to transplant does it take?** *(I'm assuming the type of donation/transplant matters... but let's just throw kidney as an example).*